# What is Logan really remembering from the time he was experimented on?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, x-men-origins-wolverine

During x-men 1, Logan is remembering/dreaming about the times he has been experimented on (which was the same experiment) which was shown to us also in Wolverine Origins or well I presume it was the same experiment where he gained his Adamantium claws.

### x-men 1

[image]
[image]

### Origins Wolverine

[image]
[image]
[image]

However I noticed that the experiment where he got his Adamantium claws in Wolverine Origins looks nothing like what Logan is remembering in his dreams in x-men 1 so my question is....

1. Is this the same experiment that he is remembering/dreaming about?
2. If not, then what experiment is it?

Sorry if this is a noob question, I am kinda new to x-men but answers would be appreciated. :)

Comment: It's not really true, but I think most fans tend to treat *X-Men Origins: Wolverine* as being less canon/accurate than the rest of the movies, and thus the X-1 memories as being more accurate.

Comment: @phantom42- Do you know why that is? I am not much of an expert on this sorry. :)

Comment: Arguably moreso than the rest of the movies, it broke canon from the comics, and generally changed characters/personalities from the comics and introduced some major inconsistencies even just within the movie universe. Things like the adamantium bullet, wolverine/sabertooth being brothers (less of an issue since comics long hinted at it), the huge personality shift of sabertooth, the creation "deadpool" (though he's never actually called that), the "emma" character (though *first class* really created the issue here)...

Comment: But in the end, currently all of the movies are canon, discrepancies be damned. Fans just hate this one movie more than the others and *want* it wiped out from canon.

Comment: I like to think that it's the same event, but Logan's memories of it in X1 are somewhat distorted.

Comment: There is no real canon to the XMen movies.  They constantly contradict one another and often toss out things that happened in other movies as if they never happened at all.

Comment: @Omegacron Seeing as that the memories come in fragments, and Xavier has to help him unlock them, this seems reasonable.

Comment: @Omegacron: I haven't seen *XMO:W*; I just assumed that Logan's amnesia was due to the fact that he had radical full-body surgery involving the application of molten metal to his skeleton, and he's immune to anesthesia. I'd expect his memories of the event to be *severely* distorted, and no fun even for the telepath who glimpses them.

Comment: @アズーサ - Go to the library and grab a copy of [Weapon X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weapon_X_(story_arc)), you'll understand where those images came from and why they made it into the movie (as for why X-Men Origins: Wolverine was non-sensical, who knows why that movie was such a train-wreck).

Comment: @Beta, you would think so, and that would have been sort of logical (and loosely adhering to the comics). In the movie, the amnesia is caused by being struck in the head by an adamantium bullet. Don't ask why this change was made, or why/how this makes any sense, because it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

The Origins movie came after X-men 1. The art direction changed since then, which accounts for the difference.

An in-story explanation is that Logan does not actually remember properly how it happened. If he remembers it is a visual reconstruction of a traumatic experience. Simply put, it's how he remembers it! The whole Adamantium bullet to the head thing makes that a pretty good memory. The writers/art directors knew this could explain the significant difference, and so they made the scene look beautiful and realistic.

Both styles fit the respective movie better, so I think it all worked out for the best. And we are left with the question, will his memories fully recover?

Answer (score 0):

Wolverine got a adamantium bullet to the head, scrambling all his Explicit Memories. In each of the movies, Wolverine has constant amnesia about who he is and his past. Amnesia can present as complete memory loss, the inability to transfer short term memory to long term, or heavily fragmented and distorted memories, based on the reason for the memory loss (In this case, extreme physical trauma). On top of that, memory is fragile thing, and recalled memories can change based on events following it or age or outcome. Memories are subjective and easy to compromise (emotions, how long ago it happened, gas lighting, etc). The brain also attempts to fill in blank spots in memory using logical conclusions. Coping mechanisms, the brain is a very complicated machine.

As his dreams are shown from his damaged point of view, the differences between what we see in Origins (The actual events) versus what Logan has nightmares about (Distorted memories) are easy to explain. **Amnesia/PTSD and subjective/damaged recall.**

Just think about last time you had a dream, and tried to remember details of it. You start filling in the blanks, but most likely, what you fill in is not what you actually dreamt.

Answer (score 0):

During one of the Blu-Ray features for X-Men Origins: Wolverine, director Gavin Hood states that both the versions of  the 'new' Alkali Lake and 'different' bonding process is because these events take place at, and I quote, "There's Alkali Lake. Here's our version of Alkali Lake." However, it is noted that this is the same director who decided to sew Deadpool's mouth shut, give him the ability to shoot optic blasts from his eyes, and embed his katanas to his arms. If Gavin Hood never comes anywhere near the X-Men franchise again, it will be too soon.